# pentaho distinct count over date

Tags: postgresql, count, distinct, pentaho

I am currently working on Pentaho and I have the following problem:

I want to get a "rooling distinct count on a value, which ignores the "group by" performed by Business Analytics. For instance:

```
Date          Field

2013-01-01    A
2013-02-05    B
2013-02-06    A
2013-02-07    A
2013-03-02    C
2013-04-03    B
```

When I use a classical "distinct count" aggregator in my schema, sum it, and then add "month" to column, I get:

```
Month          Count    Sum

2013-01        1        1
2013-02        2        3
2013-03        1        4
2013-04        1        5
```

What I would like to get would be:

```
Month          Sum

2013-01        1
2013-02        2
2013-03        3
2013-04        3
```

which is the distinct count of all Fields so far. Does anyone has any idea on this topic?

my database is in Postgre, and I'm looking for any solution under PDI, PSW, PBA or PME.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A naive approach in PDI is the following:

1. Sort the rows by the Field column
2. Add a sequence for changing values in the Field column
3. Map all sequence values > 1 to zero

These first 3 effectively flag the first time a value was seen (no matter the date).

4. Sort the rows by year/month
5. Sum the mapped sequence values by year+month
6. Get a Cumulative Sum of all the previous sums

These 3 aggregate the distinct values per month, then keep a cumulative sum. In PDI this might look something like:

[image]

I posted a Gist of this transformation [here](https://gist.github.com/mattyb149/82727922cbfa4ddfff22).

A more efficient solution is to parallelize the two sorts, then join at the latest point possible. I posted this one as it is easier to explain, but it shouldn't be too difficult to take this transformation and make it more parallel.